# How do I get rid of the big xpath overlay when using firebug

Tags: firebug

I using firebug 1.11.1 on firefox ubuntu. Its an excellent tool I use almost every day. But recently I have been getting a big black overlay annoying me sometimes.

When I as usual move the cursor over the html-code in firebug the various elements is highlighted. But if I let the cursor sit still for about half a second on one of the elements there is a big black overlay displaying the xpath of the element. Ex:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2] (http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml)
```

That could be interesting info, but since it is actually covering the whole page it is very annoying!

How could this overlay be turned off?

Comment: This seems to have solved itself after a couple of restarts.

Comment: There was a [related thread in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/0z5dg8MxM-w/discussion) lately.